# SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000 with Oracle 12c

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

I am facing critical issue with Oracle 12c [12.1.0.2.0] from Java application. 
It's mainly coming when multiple threads work on table from java application and update row having JSON CLOB field.

**Internal Error on server side:**

> ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [evaopn3()+107] [SIGSEGV]
>   [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0xCC13A8B] [Address not mapped to object] []

**Application error on java side:**

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL Error: 17410, SQLState:
>   08000
>       o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper No more data to read from socket

Spring Boot : 1.5.2.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.x + Tomcat-JDBC connection pool

**Tomcat Connection Pool Config**:

```
    final org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(requiredStringProperty("driverClassName", externalDependency, serviceName));
    dataSource.setUrl(requiredStringProperty("url", externalDependency, serviceName));
    dataSource.setUsername(requiredStringProperty("username", externalDependency, serviceName));
    dataSource.setPassword(requiredStringProperty("password", externalDependency, serviceName));
    dataSource.setValidationQuery();
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setValidationInterval(30000);
    dataSource.setInitialSize(10);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(377);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(233);
    dataSource.setMinIdle(89);
    dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(55000);
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setValidationInterval(34000);
    dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    dataSource.setAbandonWhenPercentageFull(80);
    dataSource.setMaxWait(60000);
    return dataSource;
```

**Hibernate Config:**

```
@Bean
public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", false);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 500);
    properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 1000);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", false);
    //properties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "after_statement");
    return properties; 
}
```

Comment: Could some one help me with this? I am struggling for this error from last 1 week.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with one of my query.  Looks like, added more group by in query is creating issue. I just modified the query with less group by clause and it worked.